# Local JSON file upload using request's PUT method modifies file

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, request, multipartform-data

**Summary**

I have to upload a local JSON file to the s3 using the s3 public URL. I am using the PUT method with formData to upload the file. The file is being successfully uploaded but the contents of the file are modified. To be more precise, the contents are appended by the headers of the request.

**Simplest Example to Reproduce**

I am using the following code to upload the file.

```
// Let the name of the file be **test.json**. The contents are as following:
{
  "a": "1",
  "b": "2"
}
```

the js code

```
// code starts here
const url= 'some s3 path url';
const options = {
  method: 'PUT',
  url: url,
  headers: {
    'x-amz-acl': 'bucket-owner-full-control'
  },
  formData: {
    file: fs.createReadStream(path.join('./test.json'))
  }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(chalk.bold.red(error));
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(response.body));
        return;
    }
    console.log(chalk.green.bold(response.statusCode));
})
```

**Expected Behavior**

The file should get uploaded to S3 with a similar data.

**Current Behavior**

The file gets uploaded to the S3 bucket but the contents inside the file are modified.
The new contents of the file are:

```
----------------------------054810111042388555675130
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.json"
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2"
}
----------------------------054810111042388555675130--
```

How do I modify the request to upload the file without appending these extra lines?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this? It's an urgent issue.